# ios couchbase-lite replication error

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, couchbase-lite

i am working on a ios app, that uses the replication functionality of couchbase-lite. This replication starts on a background fetch. After a few tests on a real device, it seems to work, but when i try to start this replication on a locked device there are errors like this

```
Failed to Load DB 'DBNAME': Error Domain=SQLite Code=23 "authorization denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=authorization denied}



error opening!: 23
```

When i start the app, i do the following to create the manager

```
var error:NSError?
let options:CBLManagerOptions = CBLManagerOptions(readOnly: false, fileProtection: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication)
let poptions:UnsafePointer<CBLManagerOptions> = UnsafePointer<CBLManagerOptions>.init(UnsafeMutablePointer<CBLManagerOptions>.alloc(1).initialize(options))
manager = CBLManager(directory: CBLManager.defaultDirectory(), options: poptions, error: &error)
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue? This error only appears if the iphone is locked!

Thanks.

Comment: Is your data behind a login?  What happens if you remove the login credentials and just have it be an open database on the lock device?

Comment: yes, it's because of that passcode. But it should also work in the background and with this passcode enable. It seems like ios is blocking that data access while the device is locked :/

Comment: This has to do with iOS Data Protection (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html).  Basically when you lock the device the files are encrypted and the database can not be read or written to.

Comment: [This option](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/blob/master/Source/API/CBLManager.h#L16) is available on the manager and I think it defaults to being encrypted unless the app is open.  You can try overriding this setting.

Comment: var error:NSError?
let options:CBLManagerOptions = CBLManagerOptions(readOnly: false, fileProtection: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingFileProtectionNone)
let poptions:UnsafePointer<CBLManagerOptions> = UnsafePointer<CBLManagerOptions>.init(UnsafeMutablePointer<CBLManagerOptions>.alloc(1).initialize(options))
manager = CBLManager(directory: CBLManager.defaultDirectory(), options: poptions, error: &error)

i think my code doesnt work. If i check the attributes of the created databases the fileprotection is set to NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen, so i think my code isnt working :/ Any ideas?

Comment: @Lukas  I am not able to use couch data base in background thread.Random crashes I am getting.Can u please help how u achieved the same?

Comment: lets try, but i am not really in to ios programming at the moment. Did you check the error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, see the correct initialisation of the cblmanager below:

```
var error: NSError?
let cbloptions = CBLManagerOptions(readOnly: false, fileProtection: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingFileProtectionNone)
let cblpoptions=UnsafeMutablePointer<CBLManagerOptions>.alloc(1)
cblpoptions.initialize(cbloptions)
manager = CBLManager(directory: CBLManager.defaultDirectory(), options: cblpoptions, error: &error)
```